# Why won't `electron-packager` bundle node modules that are listed in `package.json` as dependencies?

Tags: node.js, electron

I've been struggling with this for a week now so I thought I'd reach out to the amazing SO community for help. I've got an Electron project that needs to produce an OS X application (and Windows eventually). Initially we were using `webpack` to bundle everything (`electron` and front-end code) but, with the addition of some features that utilize [`ffi`](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi), this was no longer an option. After switching to using `gulp` to transpile and uglify the `electron` code, the app was working in development.

The problem I'm having is, when using [`electron-packager`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager), *none* of my `node_modules` are being bundled during the build. According to the docs, `electron-packager` *should* bundle anything listed in the `dependencies` section of `package.json`. I built a simple proof-of-concept app to simplify things and modules *still* aren't being bundled for the `electron` code. This new, simplified project is just trying to include `bunyan` (this also fails for `ffi`) but, after building, the app complains that the `bunyan` module cannot be found. Can someone help? Am I missing something small but important? Here's some detail to the project:

### Environment Details

- **OSX Version**: 10.11.6 (15G1108)
- **Node Version**: 5.2.0 (using `nvm`)
- **`npm` version**: 3.3.12

### `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "build-with-native-modules",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A test for Electron packages with native Node modules.",
    "main": "el/main.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "clean": "./node_modules/.bin/rimraf build",
      "start": "npm run clean && gulp && ./node_modules/.bin/electron ./build/dist/el/main.js",
      "electron:rebuild": "./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild",
      "build:osx": "gulp build:osx",
      "cinstall": "rm -Rf ./node_modules && npm cache clean && npm i && npm run electron:rebuild"
    },
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "author": "Zachary Abresch <zachary.abresch@gmail.com>",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
      "bunyan": "^1.8.4",
      "jquery": "^3.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
      "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
      "babel-eslint": "^7.1.0",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
      "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
      "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
      "electron": "1.4.6",
      "electron-packager": "^8.2.0",
      "electron-rebuild": "^1.3.0",
      "eslint": "^3.9.1",
      "eslint-config-airbnb": "^13.0.0",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
      "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.6.0",
      "gulp": "^3.9.1",
      "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
      "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
      "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
      "webpack": "^1.13.3",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
    }
  }
```

### `gulpfile.babel.js`

```
  import gulp from 'gulp';
  import babel from 'gulp-babel';
  import gutil from 'gulp-util';
  import webpack from 'webpack';
  import packager from 'electron-packager';

  import webpackConfig from './webpack.config.babel';
  import pack from './package.json';

  gulp.task('electron:babel', () => {
    gulp.src('src/el/**/*.js', { base: 'src' })
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/dist'));
  });

  gulp.task('move:html', () => {
    gulp.src('src/ui/**/*.html', { base: 'src' })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/dist'));
  });

  gulp.task('move:package', () => {
    gulp.src('package.json', { base: './' })
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/dist'));
  });

  gulp.task('ui:webpack', (done) => {
    const myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);

    webpack(myConfig, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) throw new gutil.PluginError('ui:webpack', err);
      gutil.log('[ui:webpack]', stats.toString({ colors: true }));
      done();
    });
  });

  const osxBuildOptions = {
    arch: 'x64',
    'app-copyright': '8x8, Inc.',
    'app-version': '1.0.0',
    'build-version': '1.0.0',
    dir: './build/dist',
    name: pack.name,
    out: './build/bundle',
    overwrite: true,
    version: pack.devDependencies.electron,
  };

  gulp.task('build:osx',
    ['move:package', 'electron:babel', 'ui:webpack', 'move:html'],
  (done) => {
    packager(osxBuildOptions, (err, appPath) => {
      if (err) throw new gutil.PluginError('electron-packager', err);
      gutil.log(`[build:osx] App built in: ${appPath}`);
      done();
    });
  });

  gulp.task('default', ['electron:babel', 'ui:webpack', 'move:html']);
```

### `webpack.config.babel.js`

```
import path from 'path';

  module.exports = {
    target: 'electron',
    entry: './src/ui/renderer.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/dist/ui'),
      filename: 'ui.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ui'),
          ],
          test: /\.js/,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

I'm considering trying out `electron-builder` but I really feel like this should be working. If anyone has any info or insight I'd greatly appreciate it. If you need any additional information, please let me know in the comments. Thanks!